# How do I create clang links to llvm?

Tags: clang, llvm, ubuntu-18.04

clang-6.0, clang-6, clang-9.0.0 and clang-9 provide several links to the LLVM compiler and library of the matching LLVM versions. My just-installed LLVM-10 does not include any links. Is there a program or script to create these links?

I can create links manually for lib and include, and hope that they work, but cannot be sure of which program is the compiler.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and will need the same on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you are wondering which of the binaries in the bin directory are the clang compiler you'll  want to look for `clang` and `clang++`. If you `file clang` you'll find that it's a symbolic link to `clang-<version>` where version is the LLVM version that Clang build was built with.

Comment: They both point to llvm-6.0. I do not expect to ever need that compiler.